# Coloring a heightmap with 1D texture in C# and openGL

Tags: c#, opengl, textures, fragment-shader

I'm been stuck on this for two days. I have a height map which plots fine.  The vertices are stored in a Vector3 with x and z regularly spaced and the height is y.  I want to color the vertices according to height which varies from 0 to 1;
I am using the opengl4CSharp libraries.  I am a complete beginner here and every example I see is for c++ and 2D textures.  So this is what I have so far.  I am sure I am missing some commands or done things wrong.
I define a byte array for the texture

```
        byte[] data = new byte[]
        {
             255, 000, 000,   
             000, 255, 000,   
             000, 000, 255   
        };
```

I then define the various opengl parameters as follows:

```
        Gl.Enable(EnableCap.Texture1D);
        Gl.PixelStorei(PixelStoreParameter.UnpackAlignment, 1);

        // Create a texture name
        var textureID = Gl.GenTexture();

        IntPtr myTexturePtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data.Length);
        Marshal.Copy(data, 0, myTexturePtr, data.Length);

     //   Marshal.FreeHGlobal(myTexturePtr);
        Gl.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture1D, textureID);

        Gl.TexParameteri(TextureTarget.Texture1D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, TextureParameter.Repeat);
        Gl.TexParameteri(TextureTarget.Texture1D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, TextureParameter.Repeat);

        Gl.TexParameteri(TextureTarget.Texture1D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, TextureParameter.Linear);
        Gl.TexParameteri(TextureTarget.Texture1D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, TextureParameter.Linear);
        Gl.TexImage1D(TextureTarget.Texture1D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Three, 3, 0, PixelFormat.Rgb, PixelType.UnsignedByte, myTexturePtr);
```

Next I do the following but I am hung up on these steps...I get an error on the samplerLocation in particular the program parameter.  What is that supposed to be?  The shader programs?

```
        uint samplerLocation = Gl.GetUniformLocation(plottingProgram, "ColorRamp");
        Gl.Uniform1i(samplerLocation, 0);
        Gl.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
        Gl.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture1D, textureID);
```

and here are the shaders

```
   public static string VertexShader = @"
    #version 130
    layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition;

    out float height;

    uniform mat4 projection_matrix;
    uniform mat4 view_matrix;
    uniform mat4 model_matrix;

    void main(void)
    {
        height = vertexPosition.y;
        gl_Position = projection_matrix * view_matrix * model_matrix * vec4(vertexPosition, 1);
    }
    ";

    public static string FragmentShader = @"
    #version 130
    uniform sampler1D colorRamp;
    in float height;

    out vec4 FragColor;
    void main(void)
    {
        FragColor = texture(colorRamp, height).rgba;
    }
    ";
```

Can somebody please help out?  Thanks

Comment: Do you have any link to their documentation? I can't seem to find anything using a few quick google searches.Specifically, is there any documentation on the `TexImage1D` function?

Comment: @gmiley Found the code [here](https://github.com/giawa/opengl4csharp/blob/ec6e54c247ea2f84391b3348bfd24c1bca039556/OpenGL/Core/Gl.cs#L2281), and [here](https://github.com/giawa/opengl4csharp/blob/5b0dad34909b4fa92dd9d359cd5363241961dd26/OpenGL/Core/GlDelegates.cs#L883) is the delegate. It's expecting a parameter which they named `data` of type `IntPtr` where OP is putting `myTexture`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a pointer to your `byte[]` like so:

```
IntPtr myTexturePtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(myTexture.Length);
Marshal.Copy(myTexture, 0, myTexturePtr, myTexture.Length);
```

Then you should be able to pass the `myTexturePtr` in place of where you are currently trying to pass `myTexture`.

```
Gl.TexImage1D(TextureTarge
    t.Texture1D, 0, 
    PixelInternalFormat.Three, 3, 0, 
    PixelFormat.Rgb, PixelType.UnsignedByte, 
    myTexturePtr);
```

Afterwards, free the pointer when you are done.

```
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(myTexturePtr);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks but the Mashal.Copy doesn't work.  I get an error " cannot convert from byte[*,*] to int[].

Comment: The marshal.copy only works with one dimensional arrays.  I could use anything as long as it works!.  I just don't know what to try here.

Comment: So I tried it with a float[] and then the program crashes whenever some openGL commands come along.

Comment: I changed the code to byte[] and now it doesn't crash.

Comment: @Tom Where is the two dimensional `byte` array coming from? You originally had a single dimensional `byte` array, which is what my answer creates an `IntPtr` pointer to. Also, you have now dramatically changed your initial question. I have answered your original question of getting a pointer to pass into the `TexImage1D` function. If you have another question, you should revert this one back to the original question, accept this answer and then create a new question.

Comment: Hi, No the original was a two dimensional array!  But it doesn't matter this was just a small part of the question.  Do I really need to mark this as answered and then repeat the whole thing over?

Comment: That is how this site works. One question per post. That prevents questions continuing on and never being resolved, as well as provides a repository for others that may be looking for a similar solution.If the question keeps changing then the original solution would no longer apply to the question being asked.

Comment: @Tom while it isn't a hard rule to limit questions to one per post (sometimes it is actually good for related questions to be posted together). It usually is best to create a new question. Even though the question is about code used in the original question, if it isn't directly related to the solution/answer, then the topic has shifted and could lead to confusion for others. This is even more important if asking the new question involves rewriting the original question to incorporate the provided original solution.